# QGIS not able to add vector layer from a folder, but can add raster layer from same folder; browser unable access that folder's contents

Tags: qgis, invalid-data, browser, qgis-browser

I've just installed version 3.28, and upon opening for the first time, I may have accidentally denied QGIS permission to access to the folders with my data.

Say my data is at */Users/me/Documents/*. When I try to add a Shapefile via Layer -> Add Layer -> Add Vector Layer (Source Type: File), I get the error message

> Invalid Data Source: /Users/me/Documents/data/filename.shp is not a valid or recognized data source.

If I move the *data* folder with shapefile and its .dbf etc. files out of the Documents folder to another location, say the desktop at
*/Users/me/Desktop/data/*,
I can then add this Shapefile.

However I can add a raster layer from the *Documents* folder.

In addition, the Browser panel in QGIS does not open the *Documents* folder, but it does open my other folders.

With the exception of raster files, it seems as if QGIS doesn't have permission to access the *Documents* folder, and I haven't been able to find where I can give permission (if this is indeed the issue).

How can I get QGIS to access this Documents folder?

Comment: Is this an OSGeo4W install or a prepackaged installer, of an update or a new install, on what platform?  You could try a re-install.  Since reinstalls don't delete your user QGIS application data folders you could rename them and see if the generated replacements work.  If not and you had lot of customizations you can delete the newly generated ones and rename the old ones back, and then look for other solutions.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/mchld5a35146/mac

Comment: Prepackaged installer of new install, MacOS 12.6.5 (I had thought I edited my question to include this, sorry). Updating preferences in System Preferences fixed this - I should have realized that...